# How to show that in function $f(x)=\frac{x}{(x+b)^2}$ maximum value of $f(x)$ is when $x = b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to show that in function $f(x)=\frac{x}{(x+b)^2}$ maximum value of $f(x)$ is when $$x = b$$?
EDIT: I saw solution using derivatives but I don't know nothing about derivatives. Can it be done without derivatives?
$b, x > 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

You want to prove that :
$$
\frac{x}{(x+b)^2}\le \frac{1}{4b}
$$
For $b>0$ becomes:  $4bx\le (x+b)^2$ and it is easy to prove that it is true for all $x$.

The case $b<0$ is for you .

Comment: There's no $b<0$ case and in fact the maximum isn't at $b$, when $b$ is negative.

Comment: @GitGud:..... but this was for Mr. Snip3r !

Comment: Hm? I mean there is no $b<0$ case in the question itself, I'm not ruining your hint. The OP edited the question and added the restriction $b>0$.

Comment: OK! I see..... all right :)

Answer (score 2):

It was shown that for $f(x)=\frac{x}{(x+b)^2}$:
$$f'(x)=\frac{(x+b)^2-2x(x+b)}{(x+b)^4}=\frac{(x+b)-2x}{(x+b)^3}=\frac{b-x}{(x+b)^3}$$
Thus, $f'(x)=0$ when $x=b$. To see $x=b$ is minimum or maximum, 
$$f''(x)=\frac{(x+b)^3(-1)-3(b-x)(x+b)^2}{(x+b)^6}=\frac{-(x+b)-3(b-x)}{(x+b)^4}=\frac{2(x-2b)}{(x+b)^4}$$
When $x=b$, $f''(x)\lt0$, hence, $x=b$ point is a maximum.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  given that $\,b,x \gt 0\,$, it follows from [AM-GM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means) that the following inequality holds, with equality iff $\sqrt{x}=\dfrac{b}{\sqrt{x}} \iff x = b$:

$$\require{cancel}
\frac{x}{(x+b)^2} \;=\; \frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{x}+\cfrac{b}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^2} \;\le\; \frac{1}{\left(2 \sqrt{\cancel{\sqrt{x}}\cfrac{b}{\cancel{\sqrt{x}}}}\,\right)^2} \;=\; \frac{1}{4b}
$$